# How to know the state of scroll (up or down) in FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

How to know the state of the scroll in FlatList?
Like scrolling up or scrolling down?
I want to know the state scrolling up or down to show or hide header in FlatList.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the `FlatList` component can use `ScrollView` props so you can use below code to find out your `Y` position of FlatList scrollbar:

```
<FlatList onScroll={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)} ...
```

You should write it on some variable and compare it with the latest change, then you can understand scrollbar moves to down or up.

**Hint**: It starts from zero.

Comment: So what's props can use to show or hide header when scrolling up and down?

Comment: Dear @ninh_nguyen, your comment can be another question. you just asked about scroll up or down.

Answer (score 2):

Use the onScroll property as below. ([Official](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscroll))

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this._onScroll} />


_onScroll = (event) {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
},
```

And for guarantee getting the value of scrolling's last frame, you need to set a property `scrollEventThrottle={16}`.

Comment: This is the only way it worked for me. Without event as parameter doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Normally, the header is called `StickyHeader`. And there is already a option called `stickyHeaderIndices` which takes the index of child to make sticky header.

[Official](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#stickyheaderindices)

```
<ScrollView
  stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
>
```

Comment: I knew stickyHeaderIndices, but with props, I can't show or hide header when scrolling up and down.