# React-native Flatlist, Run function when ScroolToTop or ScroolToBottom

Tags: react-native, flatlist

*I want to run function1() when scrollToTop and run function when scrollToBottom in flatlist. can i do that ?*

```
  <FlatList
     
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(key) => key.id}
          numColumns={2}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return (
              <View
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  flex: 1,
                  marginTop: index == 0 || 1 ? 33 : 13,
                  paddingBottom: 20,
                }}
              >
                {selectCard(item)}
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
```

*thing what i want to do that, when i want to scrolldown in flatlist, i want to hide top bar and when i want to scrollup i want to show top bar.*

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900881/how-to-know-the-state-of-scroll-up-or-down-in-flatlist) answers your question. When the `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y` inside `onScroll` method be negative the `FlatList` is scrolling to the bottom and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onScroll property as below.

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this._onScroll} />


_onScroll = (event) {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
},
```

You can pass `nativeEvent.contentOffset.y` to the event gernated by onScroll
You need to set a property

`scrollEventThrottle={10}`.